# Creating nested dictionary function using text file in Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, nested, text-files

I'm trying to create a nested if function with the username being the main string and the others being the substring. But for some reason, it does not separate the lines, creating multiple nested dictionaries instead right now it's just stuck in the first line of the text file. Plz help

MY TEXT FILE

```
shanm = null|Shanmugaraja|09/04/2002|0149606345|020409140817|0102393345|4770 4848 0109 0294
jiken = null|Soo Jiken|08/06/2000|0149600239|020908140213|011349780|8900 2828 1129 0889
```

MY CODE FOR NESTED DICTIONARY

```
with open("something.txt", 'r') as f:
    data_dict = {}
    data_dict2 = {}
    data3 = {}
    for line in f:
        f.read()
        k, v = line.strip().split("=")
        listDetails = line.strip().split('|')
        data_dict = {"Full Name": listDetails[1]}
        data_dict.update({"Date of Birth": listDetails[2]})
        data_dict.update({"Phone Number": listDetails[3]})
        data_dict.update({"Identification Card (IC) Number": listDetails[4]})
        data_dict.update({"Emergency Contact Number": listDetails[5]})
        data_dict.update({"Credit /Debit Card Details ": listDetails[6]})
        data3[k] = data_dict
 print(data3)
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
{'shanm ': {'Full Name': 'Shanmugaraja', 'Date of Birth': '09/04/2002', 'Phone Number': '0149606345', 'Identification Card (IC) Number': '020409140817', 'Emergency Contact Number': '0102393345', 'Credit /Debit Card Details ': '4770 4848 0109 0294'}}

{'jiken ': {'Full Name': 'Soo Ji', 'Date of Birth': '08/06/2000', 'Phone Number': '0149600239', 'Identification Card (IC) Number': '020908140213', 'Emergency Contact Number': '011349780', 'Credit /Debit Card Details ': '8900 2828 1129 0889'}}
```

OUTPUT RECEIVED

```
{'shanm ': {'Full Name': 'Shanmugaraja', 'Date of Birth': '09/04/2002', 'Phone Number': '0149606345', 'Identification Card (IC) Number': '020409140817', 'Emergency Contact Number': '0102393345', 'Credit /Debit Card Details ': '4770 4848 0109 0294'}}
#NOT READING THE NEXT PART OF THE LINE
```

OR (WITHOUT "F.READ()"

```
{'shanm ': {'Full Name': 'Shanmugaraja', 'Date of Birth': '09/04/2002', 'Phone Number': '0149606345', 'Identification Card (IC) Number': '020409140817', 'Emergency Contact Number': '0102393345', 'Credit /Debit Card Details ': '4770 2828 0109 0394'}}
{'shanm ': {'Full Name': 'Shanmugaraja', 'Date of Birth': '09/04/2002', 'Phone Number': '0149606345', 'Identification Card (IC) Number': '020409140817', 'Emergency Contact Number': '0102393345', 'Credit /Debit Card Details ': '4770 2828 0109 0394'}, 'jiken ': {'Full Name': 'Soo Jiken', 'Date of Birth': '08/06/2000', 'Phone Number': '0149600239', 'Identification Card (IC) Number': '020908140213', 'Emergency Contact Number': '011349780', 'Credit /Debit Card Details ': '8900 2828 1129 0889'}}
```

READS EVERYTHING ALL OVER AGAIN

Comment: when you read everything, you could separate the values with keys into two dicts afterwards. Did you try that?

Comment: `for line in f:` reads each line. Calling `f.read()` reads another line. So you're skipping every other line.

Comment: At the moment the indentation of `print(data3)` will print just one, the last, line in the loop.

Comment: You could read as a CSV using the `|` separator then process the first column into two separate keys afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

try updating your code to this:

```
with open("something.txt", 'r') as f:
    data_dict = {}
    data3 = {}
    for line in f.readlines():
        k, v = line.strip().split("=")
        listDetails = line.strip().split('|')
        data_dict = {"Full Name": listDetails[1]}
        data_dict.update({"Date of Birth": listDetails[2]})
        data_dict.update({"Phone Number": listDetails[3]})
        data_dict.update({"Identification Card (IC) Number": listDetails[4]})
        data_dict.update({"Emergency Contact Number": listDetails[5]})
        data_dict.update({"Credit /Debit Card Details ": listDetails[6]})
        data3[k] = data_dict
print(data3)
```

Comment: Why do you use lots of calls to `data_dict.update()` instead of just putting all the keys in the dictionary at once?

Comment: `data_dict = {key1: value1, key2: value2, ...}`

Comment: Or just have the keys as separate `list` and use `dict(zip())`

Comment: I agree this could be written in a cleaner way. I was focusing on solving his issue first.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a list of dictionaries. If so, you could do it like this:

```
keys = ['Full name', 'Date of Birth', 'Phone Number',
        'Identification Card (IC) Number', 'Emergency Contact Number', 'Credit /Debit Card Details']

lod = []

with open('something.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        key, v = line.split('=')
        d = {}
        for k, v in zip(keys, v.split('|')[1:]):
            d[k] = v
        lod.append({key.strip(): d})
for d in lod:
    name = list(d.keys())[0]
    print(d[name]['Full name']
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but if we put it all in a list, how can I call out a specific dictionary? becoz I want it to show a part of the dict according to the name used

Comment: I'll add something to the end of the code which may help you

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = ["Full Name", "Date of Birth", "Phone Number",
        "Identification Card (IC) Number", "Emergency Contact Number",
        "Credit /Debit Card Details "]
data = {}
with open("something.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, values = line.strip().split(" = ") # note the space around =, to avoid trailing space in key
        values = values.split('|')
        data[key] = dict(zip(keys, values[1:]))}

print(data)
print(data.get('jiken'))
```

Probably you want to store each dict `data` in some sort of container type like `list`.

UPDATE: I edited my code to create a dict and access each record by username.

Comment: one more thing, i can't seem to call out a dict with the key value (username). May I know how would you add that in ur code

Comment: If I understand what you ask, you want to have all records in a dict and access individual records by key username, e.g. `jiken'. I updated my answer to do that.